# In Android, how to re-layout views?

Tags: android

I am adding a series of custom views to a LinearLayout.  I have overridden the onMeasure method of these custom views, to return the dimensions based on certain parameters.  Based on user input, I would like to change these parameters, to change the size of the views.  How can I force the LinearLayout to "re-layout" it's children, to reflect the new dimensions?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Oh... linearLayout.requestLayout().

Comment: invalidate() wasn't useful didn't work for me, I assume because invalidating a layout forces all it's children to re-draw themselves, but does not actually resize/relayout the children.

Comment: On Android OS 4.x tablet (ICS), relayouting did not help for me. What did help, was removing `getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);`

Answer (score 14):

my case is I need to to relayout all children immediately.
requestLayout() does not do it immediately.

For those who have the same requirement with me:

This will force relayout the view's children immediately (given that view's own width and height does not need to change)

```
private void reLayoutChildren(View view) {
    view.measure(
        View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(view.getMeasuredWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
        View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(view.getMeasuredHeight(), View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
    view.layout(view.getLeft(), view.getTop(), view.getRight(), view.getBottom());
}
```

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me.  `invalidate` and `requestLayout` just wouldn't do it, so thanks for this tip!